# IOS - how to write file to network share?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, share, unc

i'm trying to create and write a file to a network share (smb). i have some data stored in an NSData object and need to write the content to a network share at \\media\file.xml

any help or advise would be greatly appreciated! thanks!